# Xcode 5.0 - where is "Documents" in Organiser?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I installed Xcode 5.0 after previously using Xcode 4.6, and I don't see "Documents" in the Organiser toolbar anymore. I see only "Devices", "Projects", and "Archives". Where is "Documents" in Xcode 5.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation has been split out into its own window which you can get to from *Help → Documentation and API Reference* or by hitting *⌥⌘?*.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it by mere seconds. :)